# How to set Form Field Line Class

Tags: php, atk4

I added a field of type line to form. It created a field and inside that field is field with tag input. How can I set that input class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$form->addField('line','input')->setAttr('class','myclass');
```

should do it.